# How do I know if a car is RWD, FWD, 4WD or FWD before purchasing it?

Tags: need-for-speed-payback

Let's say that I want to buy a 4WD/AWD Off Road vehicle: How can I know if the vehicle is RWD, FWD, 4WD or FWD before purchasing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to determine what drivetrain your car will have before purchasing it in-game. There are few external resources that provide this information as well, with the [NFS Wikia](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Cars_sorted_by_drivetrain) being the only webpage I could find and vastly out-of-date.

Sorry, but it doesn't seem like there are any resources to reconcile this.